# Razor custom viewbase properties are not populated

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have created a custom razor view base class and added some properties to ease my development, but the problem is thy are not getting populated!

here is custom base class code

```
    public abstract class WebViewPage<TModel> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public string MetaTagKeywords { get; set; }
    public string MetaTagDescription { get; set; }
    public string MetaTagTitle { get; set; }
    public string ExtraScripts { get; set; }
}

public abstract class WebViewPage : WebViewPage<dynamic>
{
}
```

and here is what I do in razor view to populate it

```
@MetaTagTitle =" test title"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The razor code:

```
@MetaTagTitle =" test title"
```

Does not execute an assign, but outputs the contents of MetaTagTitle followed by the rest of the line.

It is translated to something like this (not exactly, just to get the point):

```
Response.Write(Html.Encode(MetaTagTitle));
Response.Write(" = \" test title\"");
```

What you need is:

```
@{ MetaTagTitle = "test title"; }
```

This will execute the code, and does not try to display it.

Comment: If anyone can help, this will only works if i add @inherits "my Custom base class" even though i have added it to Razor section in webconfig

Comment: @user: That's a totally different question (no experience with that, yet). I suggest you create a new question. Keeps the SO database tidy and you will also get renewed attention.